# Direction of forces due to pressure

Tags: fluid-dynamics, vector-fields

If I understood correctly then if you have a 'pressure field' and you have a pressure difference between two points in it, then there is a force acting. (This is the explanation of Archimedes principle , the upthrust is due to pressure difference at top and bottom of immersed object)

So, I've started to think of pressure as a 'potential' of sorts sort of like 'voltage'. Now the problem is you define pressure using the equation

$${p} * \vec{dA} = \vec{dF}$$

But on the other hand, $$\vec{F} = -q \nabla V$$

What is weird to mean is that voltage is  related to force (indirectly) by an integral while pressure is a potential defined using a derivative of sorts.

Particularly speaking can 'potential functions' be both defined by derivatives and integrals? I was of the opinion that you can only get them using integrals

Now coming to the main question, clearly force points in the direction of steepest descent of potential in the electrodynamics case. However how would one figure out the direction due to pressure?

Comment: There is a direct analogy between the current flowing in a conductor due to a voltage gradient, and the flow through a porous medium due to a pressure gradient. Perhaps you can look up Darcy's law and Ohm's law and view the analogies.

Comment: I have heard of the analogies but I don't think they particularly address the issue I'm having in the problem

Comment: Pressure can not generally treated as a potential.

Comment: Well I'm not accustomed with rigorous definition of the word potential but if I were ot put precisely what I meant, I was talking about how pressure is a scalar fielD and also the fact that pressure difference causes force ( similar to the gradient of regular potential)

Comment: The magnitude of pressure can be treaded as a field, But pressure is really the isotropic part of the stress tensor, and, as an isotropic 2nd order tensor, it acts equally in all directions.  This is Pascal's principle.

Comment: I haven't reached to tensors but I think I get what you mean. However I don't think this is a complete answer

Comment: @DDD4C4U - I think that you need to clarify your question then. The net force on an element of material is indeed directly related to the pressure gradient.  The pressure gradient is a vector quantity and does have a direction. The net force is in the opposite direction of the pressure gradient. Is that all you are asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a material that cannot support shear stresses, i.e. in the inviscid approximation, the equations of static equilibrium can be written as:

$$-\nabla p + {\bf b} = 0$$

where ${\bf b}$ is the external force per unit volume required to equilibrate the pressure gradient. Hence the force per unit volume due to the pressure gradient itself is $-\nabla p$. Let's call that ${\bf b}_p$.  Then we can integrate ${\bf b}_p$ over the entire volume of the sample to get the net force due to the pressure on the sample as:

$${\bf F}_{net}=\int_V {\bf b}_p dV=\int_V -\nabla p dV$$

Applying the divergence theorem to the far right-hand side gives:

$${\bf F}_{net}=-\int_S p{\bf n} dS$$

This is exactly what you should expect, and the integral of the external body force over the volume will then equilibrate this net force due to the pressure.

Comment: I liked the answer but I think there could mbe more discussion about the theory

Comment: @DDD4C4U - Thanks. What aspect are you asking for more discussion on?

Comment: 1. where your original equation comes from
2. How does one find direction of pressure
3. Ok this is just an extra thing but how would one find an equation modelling a pressure field? like how would you construct one?

Comment: @DDD4C4U 1. That is the equation for static equilibrium in a continuum that cannot support shear stress. If you look into the Navier-Stokes equations this is what would result without the shear stresses or inertia terms, i.e. set viscosity and density to zero. 2. Pressure does not have a direction. It is the trace of the stress tensor, and is a scalar. Pressure gradient has a direction, and the normal to any surface that pressure is acting on has a direction. 3. That question is too broad to answer. In what type of material?

Comment: 3. Say for example a bucket of water

Comment: @DDD4C4U The external body force is then just $-\rho g \bf k$. Integrating the equilibrium equation then gives $p = -\rho g z + p_0$. Solve for the constant $p_0$ using a point where you know the pressure, e.g. the pressure is atmospheric pressure at the surface of the water in the bucket.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a small cube of liquid in equilibrium, oriented according an arbitrary cartesian axis: $F_z(z + \Delta z) + \delta B_z - F_z(z) = 0$, where $\delta B_z$ is the component of a body force (the weight for example) in $z$ direction.

For a generic material, $F_z$ would produce normal and shear stresses. For a liquid with negligible viscosity, only normal stress is meaningful: $(\Delta x \Delta y)(\sigma_z(z + \Delta z) - \sigma_z(z)) + \delta B_z = 0$

The same for the other axis, resulting in:

$$\Delta x \Delta y\Delta \sigma_z + \delta B_z = 0$$
$$\Delta x \Delta z\Delta \sigma_y + \delta B_y = 0$$
$$\Delta y \Delta z\Delta \sigma_x + \delta B_x = 0$$

Dividing by $\Delta V = \Delta x \Delta y \Delta z$ and taking the limit when $\Delta V$ tends to zero:

$$\frac{\partial \sigma_z}{\partial z} + b_z = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial \sigma_y}{\partial y} + b_y = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial \sigma_x}{\partial x} + b_x = 0$$

where $b_i$ are the components of the body force per unit of volume.

Besides the absence of shear stresses, all normal stresses are equal at a given point of a liquid, so we can call them by the same name: $-p(x,y,z)$. The minus sign is because they are compressive stresses in the volume element.

We can then write, (and now taking $\mathbf b = \mu \mathbf g$):

$$\nabla p - \mu \mathbf g = 0$$

Comment: This was from feynman wasn't it :D

Comment: No, from a book of theory of elasticity. The trick of dividing by the volume is very nice.